NativeScript services error when try use a axios or other webservice library. webpack errors
I create a simple android hello-world project (nativescript angular) latest or v17 and it run normal, then I install axios npm i axios if I try a simples get a lot errors happens. I installed some different libraries to webservice consume and always I'm getting the same error:
   async loadCities() {
    try {

      const response = await axios.get(this.getPath('some'), {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${this.apiKey}`
        }
      })
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error('loadCities-> error: ', error)
    }
  }

errors happens before install on device emulator or physical device.
ERROR in ./node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js 1:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Users\m\Desktop\nsAplicativo\node_modules\combined-stream\lib'

    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
            - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
            - install 'util'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
            resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
    ...

even after install a lot this libraries, the error continues:
    npm install 'stream-browserify'
    npm install 'path-browserify'
    npm install 'url'
    npm install 'os-browserify'
    npm install 'stream-http'
    npm install 'https-browserify'
    npm install 'assert'

Can you give a light about this problem?
